# How could I verify that a contract was actually sent to me from the client as soon as the contract is received?

Tags: authentication, key, algorithm

If I want to store electronic contracts for clients over a long period of time. I need to make sure that those files are not readable by anyone other than the client until the client retrieves them at a later time. But, I do need to be able to verify that a contract was actually sent to me from the client as soon as the contract is received. How could this be done? what would the client do, and what algorithms would they use? What would I do, and what algorithms would I use?

Comment: I don't have experience in electronic contracts. However, if you expect only client to know about it then client must implement responsibility of both encryption and decryption. That is client, encrypt and send data to server and when required client can request from server and decrypt.  Now to address the verification part, server could ask to authenticate client before it allow a given client to store encrypted contract.

Comment: Can anyone expand on this? What kind of algorithms?

Comment: What's your service? Store and verify arbitrary files without knowing their contents, but providing an independent 3rd party evidence that it existed at a certain time?

Comment: @Esa Jokinen it is a law firm and I need to make sure that those  files are not readable by anyone other than the client until the client retrieves them at a later time. However, I do need to be able to verify that a contract was actually sent to them by the client as soon as the contract is received.

Comment: There's some overlap here with [Trusted Timestamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping)